# Current location error

Tags: android

I am using this lines of code to get the current location and access the latitude and longitude of that location, but now, out of no where the latitude and longitude are saved with 0.0 and 0.0. Can someone tell me why that happened?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getLocation();
}

void getLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

    }else{
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null){
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();

           Log.e("Latitude: ",latti+"");
            Log.e("Longitude: ",longi+"");
        } else {
            Log.e("Eroare!!!" , "");
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            getLocation();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/9240225/andy95 CHECK MY ANSWER BELOW, it will solve your crash problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are trying to access addresses from your List , but sometime it can be of 0 size , so before accessing just add a condition ,** *it will avoid your app crash and will work fine .*

use this below code in place of your code :-

```
  Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MainActivity.latitude, MainActivity.longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()>0) {    // add check if addresses size is greater than 0 , means there is some object. 
            Log.e(TAG , addresses+"");
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            currentLocation.setText(city + ", " + state);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is the latitude and longitude. They are saved as 0.0 both. Now I have to ask why...

Comment: your app is not crashing because of Lat long value , it crashed because of               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: if you add this above code your app will not crash , hope it helps you

Comment: did you try this code from my answer , it will solve your crash problem , hope it helps you , let me know if anything

Comment: It did. It saved the crush problem. But now I changed the question cause I found why it start to crush like that. My latitude and longitude are saved as 0.0 and 0.0. The problem is that i did not even changed that code so it had no reason to be like this.

Comment: make a new question and put all your code there so i can help you in that problem too

Comment: it seems your location object value is coming as null , put a Log inside your else part in getLocation() method

Comment: what you do is - enable your location and go to that page twice , first time it will give null if lastKnownLocation is not there , then second time when you go to that screen it should give you the value , put a log and let me know the result of these logs in both times.

Comment: I can't make a now question now. I have to wait 3 hours or something like that. The thing is that yesterday, it worked perfectly and now it has this problem.